# Unable to start activity component info (nullpointer)

Tags: android

im trying to make a basic ui in android with tabs. however i keep getting a nullpointer exception whenever i try to run it. the error originates from initializing viewpager. (i dont know what else to type and i keep receiving an error whenever i try to post.)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {
ActionBar actionBar;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager=(ViewPager) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new adapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab stocks = actionBar.newTab();
    stocks.setText("Stocks");
    stocks.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab market = actionBar.newTab();
    market.setText("Market");
    market.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab portfolio = actionBar.newTab();
    portfolio.setText("Portfolio");
    portfolio.setTabListener(this);

    actionBar.addTab(stocks);
    actionBar.addTab(market);
    actionBar.addTab(portfolio);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainsearch, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

class adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if(arg0==0) {
            fragment = new StocksFragment();
        }
        if (arg0==1){
            fragment = new MarketFragment();
        }
        if (arg0==2){
            fragment = new PortfolioFragment();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this line will give a `NPE`

```
 viewPager=(ViewPager) viewPager.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```

you are calling a method on an object that you are trying to initialize (calling `findViewById()` on null `viewPager`)

If `tabs` is in `activity_main.xml` then just remove `viewPager`

```
viewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```

Answer (score -1):

findViewById is a method of the activity, not of the view. So it should be:

```
viewPager=(ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It is exactly the answer to the question.

Comment: It does show what part of the code is wrong and what it should be (except `this` is unnecessary). The problem is that one line and/or code only answers are typically bad form on SO and this one has both. You should try to provide some explanation no matter how obvious you think it is